# Difference between NCBI's /genomes and /1000genomes

Tags: bioinformatics, genomes, data, ncbi

Wondering what the difference is in the data hosted here:

- ftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nih.gov/1000genomes
- ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/genomes/

Also (sidenote), would be interested to note what the difference between `ftp-trace` and just `ftp` is. But there is probably over 1TB of data in `/genomes`, and I assume something of "a thousand genomes" is in `/1000genomes`, but I'm not sure what data exactly. Would like to know what is i thse two folders, and where the 1000genomes data is exactly. It looks like [/1000genomes/ftp/data/](ftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nih.gov/1000genomes/ftp/data/) has "sequence data", but I'm not sure how that compares to the `/genomes` list of species names (and I'm also not sure what "sequence data" entails exactly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest difference is the scale and range. The aim of [1000 genome project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1000_Genomes_Project) was to provide comprehensive library of **human** genetic variation. DNA of individuals coming from different ethnic groups, geographic locations were sequenced and the results of the study were published [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature09534).

Genomes from NCBI come from different organisms and the number of sequenced individuals differ between species (including human). This database is constantly growing. Detailed description can be found [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/guide/genomes-maps/).

Answer (score 1):

In fact these two things are very different and I would say quite opposite.

NCBI genomes are collection of information on genomes of various species including sequences, maps, chromosomes, assemblies, and annotations. Basically it's a catalog of reference genomes.

1KG is a catalog of human genetic variations from a genome-wide association study.